# Observer class not receiving notifications

Tags: ios, swift, notificationcenter

I have a class that handles the notification.  I can add the observer to NotificationCenter but the handles method never executes.  If I move the same method into the class that adds the observer it works fine.

I've tried putting it in the class and it works fine just not from a different object.  This is on Swift 4.2.  I have also printed out all the observers via: `print("Exp - NC - \(NotificationCenter.default.debugDescription)")`
 and can see the observer was added for the `.purchase` name.

// Works

**SomeClass.swift**

```
// Works assuming notify handler is in this class
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notify(_:)), name: .purchase, object: nil)
```

// Does not work

**MyObserver.swift**

```
import Foundation

@objc
public class MyObserver: NSObject {

    @objc
    public override init() {
        print("Observer here creating a new instance")
    }

    @objc public func onNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("Observer 1 here notifying event")
    }
}
```

**SomeClass.swift**

```
let myObserver = MyObserver()  

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(myObserver, selector: 
#selector(myObserver.onNotification(_:)), name: .purchase, object: 
nil)
```

Note: .purchase is an extension of Notification.Name

I would expect it to notify via the myObserver class as well.  Seems like it only works with `self`.  The only difference is the observer is a custom object instead of `self`

Comment: Sounds like `myObserver` or `SomeClass` might be going out-of-scope? Where are you creating `SomeClass`, and are you retaining it? Same question for `myObserver`...

Comment: @DonMag yeah the observer was being dealloc'ed.  If i move the observer to a class level var then it retains the object in memory to take action on the notification.

Comment: @DonMag thanks for the help.